# How can I get a column with real gene names in my ballgown analysis?

Tags: r, rna-seq, differential-expression

I am doing RNAseq analysis and I am using ballgown procedure for it.

There is an option in R to calculate differentially expressed genes and use FPKM in calculating differential gene expression, which is the following:

```
results_genes = stattest(bg_filt, feature="gene", covariate="state", getFC=TRUE, meas="FPKM")
```

When accessing head(results_genes) there is a column named `id` that contain gene names.

While some genes contain more or less readable names, others look like `gene-LOC100037748, gene-LOC100037751, gene-LOC100037760` etc...

Can I create a column with real gene names that correspond to these? Is there a sort of API or something maybe?